# RGBA Image format (as used by Scintilla)

Tags: c#, rgba, scintilla

I'm working with [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) (not [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)), and I'm trying to set the images used in the auto complete list. Scintilla requires a string of bytes/pixels in the RGBA format.

**Scintilla's description of this RGBA format:** ([Quote from documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Images))

> The RGBA format allows translucency with an alpha value for each
>   pixel. It is simpler than XPM and more capable.
>
> The data is a sequence of 4 byte pixel values starting with the pixels
>   for the top line, with the leftmost pixel first, then continuing with
>   the pixels for subsequent lines. There is no gap between lines for
>   alignment reasons.
>
> Each pixel consists of, in order, a red byte, a green byte, a blue
>   byte and an alpha byte. The colour bytes are not premultiplied by the
>   alpha value. That is, a fully red pixel that is 25% opaque will be
>   [FF, 00, 00, 3F]

I expect that I'm misunderstanding the format explained above, the documentation is not very clear.

**My Conversion Method:**

I wrote this function to convert a PNG into this string of bytes:

```
public static string ConvertFromPNG(Bitmap PNG)
{
    string rgba = "";

    int pixWidth = PNG.Width;
    int pixHeight = PNG.Height;

    for (var y = 0; y < pixHeight; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < pixWidth; x++)
        {
            Color pix = PNG.GetPixel(x, y);

            rgba += pix.R.ToString("X2") + pix.G.ToString("X2") + pix.B.ToString("X2") + pix.A.ToString("X2");
        }
    }

    return rgba;
}
```

**The Resulting Image:**

But Scintilla is just showing the image as a grey box:

[image: Autocomplete box].

The image in question is a copy of one of [Microsoft's Babel images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166402%28v=vs.80%29.aspx): [image: Babel icon].

I know that the set of bytes is correct because interestingly, if I format them in lines and zoom out on them I can see the outline of the image:

[image: Bytes(Zoomed out in image editor)]

**Bytes Generated:**

```
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
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are formatting the bytes as hex values and placing them in a string. Scintilla just wants the bytes themselves.

I suspect you want to create a byte array rather than a string, and store into it the values of `pix.R`, `pix.G`, `pix.B`, and `pix.A` directly, rather than formatting them as strings.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. The documentation says the method expects a string of bytes, that's what confused me :)

Answer (score 0):

After accepting JasonD's answer I've updated my code and it's working. In case it helps anyone else, here is the working code:

```
public static byte[] ConvertFromPNG(Bitmap PNG)
{
    byte[] rgbaB = new byte[4 * (PNG.Width * PNG.Height)];

    int i = 0;

    for (var y = 0; y < PNG.Height; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < PNG.Width; x++)
        {
            Color pix = PNG.GetPixel(x, y);

            rgbaB[i++] = pix.R;
            rgbaB[i++] = pix.G;
            rgbaB[i++] = pix.B;
            rgbaB[i++] = pix.A;
        }
    }

    return rgbaB;
}
```